# How did you learn the hard way to "never trust client data"?

Tags: user-input, strong-parameters, exploit, sanitization

I'm interested in stories where not sanitizing, validating or "sane"-atizing client submitted data in a web application caused a real life problem.

I think if we get some interesting answers this could be a good link to send new web developers so that they can learn from the mistake of others.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the most of the exploits I read recently:
[Xss exploits](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)